# Why does not std::sqrt() work correctly on double data in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, double, sqrt, tdm-gcc

Here is a simple code in C++ which I am compiling using **TDM-GCC 5.1 32bit** (gcc-5.1.0-tdm-1-core) on a Windows 8.1 **64bit** Intel core i-7 machine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double a, b;
    a = 0.002;
    b = 0.004;
    cout << std::sqrt(a*a+b*b)<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But on running, it gives the following output

```
nan
```

However, it works correctly with TDM-GCC 32bit compiler on a **32 bit machine**.

Also, when I am changing the datatype to **float**, it is working properly on both 32bit and 64 bit computers.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Works ok on Linux/x86-64 (Debian/Sid) with GCC 5.2

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It also works correctly on MSVC 2012.

Comment: Use `-S` and compare the assembly output between the two GCCs. Or, at least, attach the two executables.

Comment: Seems to [work as indented](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0bc69e84e0009b5).

Comment: Interestingly, something like Clang won't even [execute the computation](https://goo.gl/9WD1V1) at runtime.

Comment: Compile with `g++ -O -fverbose-asm -S` and look inside the produced `.s` assembler file

Comment: Here is the assembly output link: [link](http://pastebin.com/ikdqVfxM) from `g++ -O -fverbose-asm -S`

Comment: I need some time to compare the two versions since I don't have the 32bit computer right now.

Comment: Works well for me - Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)

Comment: Glad you found what the problem was. Can you post your final update as an answer?

Comment: @CássioRenan Surely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is as follows:

It was compiled inherently in the Code::Blocks with the following command (narrowed):

```
g++.exe -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\lib" -o main.exe main.cpp -lm
```

where **C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\lib** has an old math library named **libm.a**.

So, on putting `-lm` along with `-L"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\lib"`, it is found using **Process Explorer** that **main.exe** is using that corresponding old **libm5.dll** which seems to be incompatible.

So, if **at least one of the options** `-lm` or `-L"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\lib"` is **removed** and compiled as follows:

```
g++.exe -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\lib" -o main.exe main.cpp
```

or

```
g++.exe -o main.exe main.cpp -lm
```

or

```
g++.exe -o main.exe main.cpp
```

it is not linking the old `libm.a` and hence running correctly.